# dynamic Access-Control-Allow-Origin header serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

I have configured a serverless function as below

```
id:
  handler: id.get
  events:
    - http:
        path: id
        method: get
        cors:
          origin: ""
          headers:
            - Content-Type
            - X-Amz-Date
            - Authorization
            - X-Api-Key
            - X-Amz-Security-Token
            - x-access-token
          allowCredentials: true
```

Code in my handler function is as below

```
let headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': event.headers.Origin ? event.headers.Origin : event.headers.origin,
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
}
callback(null, {
  "isBase64Encoded": false,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": headers,
  "body": JSON.stringify(body),
  "multiValueHeaders": multiValueHeaders
})
```

I am getting response to `OPTIONS` request as

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

Due to that I am getting the below error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/dev/id' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I want the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should be dynamic(origin of the request), How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new method `options` with the below code

```
module.exports.options = async (event, context, callback) => {
  const origin = event.headers.Origin || event.headers.origin;
  context.succeed({
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Accept,Accept-Language,Content-Language,Content-Type,Authorization,x-correlation-id,x-access-token",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": origin ? origin : '*',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    },
    statusCode: 204
  });
};
```

serverless.yml

```
options:
  handler: id.options
  events:
    - http:
        path: id
        method: options
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to this config:

```
id:
  handler: id.get
  events:
    - http:
        path: id
        method: get
        cors:
          origin: "*"
          headers:
            - Content-Type
            - X-Amz-Date
            - Authorization
            - X-Api-Key
            - X-Amz-Security-Token
            - x-access-token
          allowCredentials: true
```

Comment: @vanderson origin with * will not allow credentials.
FYI https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials